# apply a list of functions to one argument

Tags: python

Let's say we have a list of functions

```
funcs = [int, float]
```

and we want to apply them to one argument `0` to get `[0, 0.0]`

Clearly we can (edit: and should!) do

```
[f(0) for f in funcs]
```

but is there any other machinery for this in the standard library, akin to the `map` function?

Comment: It's not clear why you want to avoid the list comprehension - what's the *problem* you're trying to solve?

Comment: To clarify further, *using a library* to perform the work of a list comprehension doesn't sound like a good idea.

Comment: `list(f(0) for f in funcs)` -- technically not a list comprehension :)

Comment: Voted to reopen. While the question may be pretty pointless, it is not at all "unclear" what is being asked here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> from operator import methodcaller
>>> funcs = [int, float]
>>> map(methodcaller('__call__', 0), funcs)
[0, 0.0]
```

Pointless but possible.

Answer (score 2):

The list comprehension here is the preferred method. However, if you wanted to avoid the list comprehension, you can use `map()`:

```
map(lambda f: f(0), funcs)
#[0, 0.0]
```

But in python3 you would need to wrap the call to `map()` with `list` since `map()` returns an iterator:

```
list(map(lambda f: f(0), funcs))
```

But as @jonrsharpe [mentioned in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49387445/apply-a-list-of-functions-to-one-argument-in-python/49387488#comment85776274_49387488), this is not recommended as it [wastefully creates a list](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html#views-and-iterators-instead-of-lists).

#### Timing Results

On my computer running python 2.7

```
#List comprehension
%%timeit
[f(0) for f in funcs]
#1000000 loops, best of 3: 352 ns per loop

#map + lambda
%%timeit
map(lambda f: f(0), funcs)
#1000000 loops, best of 3: 687 ns per loop

#generator
list(f(0) for f in funcs)
#1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.1 µs per loop

#map + methodcaller
%%timeit
map(methodcaller('__call__', 0), funcs)
#1000000 loops, best of 3: 687 ns per loop
```

- The slowest solution (by far) is the generator method suggested by @timgeb in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49387445/apply-a-list-of-functions-to-one-argument/49387488#comment85776490_49387445).
- List comprehension is the fastest
- Both solutions using `map()` are second fastest.

Comment: That's only a list in Python 2.x...

Comment: `list(map(...))` if this is Python 3

Comment: He already knows about map: > "perhaps with some library function akin to map?"

Comment: @Wondercricket [what's new](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html#views-and-iterators-instead-of-lists) *specifically* suggests not doing that, and using a list comprehension instead.

Comment: map + lambda: useless. Use listcomp instead.